# .htaccess Redirect main domain to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using one account for multi sites and I am wanting to have a clean `public_html` dir so I am trying to create my `.htaccess` to redirect the main domain to the subfolder.

I currently have as my result `http://domain.co.nz/subfolder`.

How can I work it so it just shows the original domain and also for www/http?

**Code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.co.nz$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust your code a little.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.co\.nz$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: If that didn't work, you can try this way. See the updated rule.